# Django-tastypie. Output in JSON to the browser by default

Tags: django, json, tastypie

I see 'Sorry, not implemented yet. Please append "?format=json" to
your URL.'. I need always append string "?format=json". Can I make a
output in JSON by default?

Regards,
Vitaliy

Answer (score 41, accepted):

From the [tastypie cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#determining-format-via-url), in order to change the default format, you need to override the determine_format() method on your ModelResource:

```
class MyResource(ModelResource):
    ....
    def determine_format(self, request):
        return 'application/json'
```

The above link demonstrates alternative methods of determining output format.

Also, I don't think a valid answer is essentially "You don't need this".

**Edit**

It appears GregM's answer is probably (I haven't tested it) the most correct with the new version of TastyPie, [as per documentation](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html#tastypie-default-formats) putting the following in your `settings.py` will restrict the serialization output to json.

```
 TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS = ['json']
```

Comment: `TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS` rules!

Comment: What if you want JSON to be the default, but also to support XML if requested?

Comment: djangorestframework users visit : http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/settings/

Answer (score 10):

As of tastypie [0.9.13](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/commit/905ae88f4c6a4d1cdf5314ff807689461dd7631e), if you do not need XML support you can disable it globally by setting `TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS` to just `['json']` in your `settings.py` file.  Requests should then default to JSON.

Comment: One of those times where I wish I could give more than one ☝️ rec to a thing.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested setting TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS to ['json'] but it doesn't prevent the "Sorry not implemented yet" message when viewing the API from a browser.

I *am* able to make that warning go away by forcing the "Accept" header to 'application/json' in a middleware:

```
class TastyJSONMiddleware(object):
    """
    A Django middleware to make the Tastypie API always output in JSON format
    instead of telling browsers that they haven't yet implemented text/html or
    whatever.

    WARNING: This includes a hardcoded url path for /api/.  This is not 'DRY'
    because it means you have to edit two places if you ever move your API
    path.
    """

    api_prefix = '/api/'

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith(self.api_prefix):
            request.META['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 1):

To examine/test your REST API, use a Rest client instead of a browser, preferably one that knows how to pretty print JSON.  I use the Postman plugin for Google Chrome.

If you want pretty json in command line:

```
curl https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json | python -m json.tool
```

Answer (score 1):

Tasytpie has the defaults set as 'application/json'. But that is overridden by Browser request.

According to Tastypie, the default is overridden by ***Request Header* ACCEPT** and your format specification in **GET** ie. *?format=json*. When you send request from browsers, if you see the Request HTTP Header sent, its something like -

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

The **application/xml** overrides the default in Tastypie Resource. Therefore, either you can set Browser Header to have 'application/json' (Bad idea) or you just specify in GET.

If you hit the same API url using CURL, you will see the JSON output without specifying that in GET.