# Django + AngularJS: Recommendations on restful integration

Tags: django, angularjs

Does anybody have any recommendations on how to integrate AngularJS with a current Django project?  I have no experience with AngularJS but I like the asynchronous loading and update of objects, so it seems time to learn.  There seem to be a lot of django and AngularJS pypi apps, but is that the best way to integrate?

Any advice on AngularJS integration with Django would be great.

Thanks

Comment: There is no advices how to deal with each others, because your API shouldn't rely on frontend technology. And AngularJS app should be build from reusable parts that do not rely only on backend tech. The glue thing are RESTful rules. If you manage to make frontend and backend be RESTful, that will solve all integrations problems etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could develop REST api, which returns responses in rest format, you could use tastypie for example.

Related topic how to return in json is here [Django-tastypie. Output in JSON to the browser by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649387/django-tastypie-output-in-json-to-the-browser-by-default)

Comment: I really would like to learn and use AngularJS.  Do you have any advice on integration?

Comment: Did you look at AngularJS? The integration is done using JSON api.
Please look here http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11 - in this tutorial it means, that your server should provide responses in json format

Looking at previous link you could check, how to make json rest api using django on serverside

Comment: http://blog.mourafiq.com/post/55034504632/end-to-end-web-app-with-django-rest-framework one more tutorial
you could go through it and get the main idea