# Django Tastypie: Output JSON by defaut, but support other formats too?

Tags: django, tastypie

I am migrating an existing API from Django Piston to Django Tastypie. I am using Django 1.7.

The existing API outputs JSON by default, but supports XML queries if `?format=xml` is appended to the URL.

I am finding it hard to work out how to replicate this in Tastypie. There's [a very similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649387/django-tastypie-output-in-json-to-the-browser-by-default), but all the answers only explain how to totally disable all other formats except JSON. So I'm wondering if it's actually possible to do this in Tastypie.

If I do this in my settings file:

```
TASTYPIE_DEFAULT_FORMATS = ['json']
```

JSON becomes the default, but I can't then output XML with a `?format=xml` parameter, because XML is disabled.

Similarly if I add a `determine_format` method to the resource.

Is it possible to specify JSON as the default format, but also allow XML?

Comment: Did you set the "serializer" attribute in your ModelResources's ``meta`` class? See: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/serialization.html

Answer (score 0):

You can override the determine_format for default format as JSON. It will work for other format too.

```
class MyAppResource(ModelResource):
    """It is inheriting Model Resources of tastypie"""

    def determine_format(self, request):
        """
        return application/json as the default format
        """
        fmt = determine_format(request, self._meta.serializer,\
                               default_format=self._meta.default_format)
        if fmt == 'text/html' and 'format' not in request:
            fmt = 'application/json'
        return fmt
```

Now, Instead of Base as ModelResource use MyAppResource for your Resource classes.